# Why do we only do for one depth decision tree for amoeba problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Amoeba Question: A population of amoeba starts with 1. After 1 period, that amoeba can divide into 1, 2, 3, or 0 (it can die) with equal probability. What is the probability that the entire population will die out eventually?

The answer is generally given as the solution to :

$P=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}P + \frac{1}{4}P^2 + \frac{1}{4}P^3$

Isn't it possible the amoeba, maybe let's say split into 2 and again split into 2 and then the 4 die?
Basically

$P=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}P + \frac{1}{4}P^2 +  \frac{1}{4}P^3 + \frac{1}{16}P^4 + ...( \text{and other such possibilites}) $

Do we not go into deeper depth since it doesn't change the answer much or am I approaching the solution the wrong way?

Comment: That's the magic of recursion. By way of analogy, if you wanted to know how many descendants you'll ever have, and you have two children, you only need to add up each of their descendants, and add them to those two children. You don't also have to add your grandchildren's descendants, and your great-grandchildren's descendants, etc. All you need is for the next layer of recursion to be expressible in terms of the original expression.

Comment: I advise you to write a computer program simulating this experiment a large number of times. The profit will be at two levels 1) Benefit in the execution with for example rare cases upcome, 2) Benefit on the coding side with different ways of coding reflecting different equivalent (?) approaches.